# MVC allow an IIS default page in subfolder without breaking parent route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I need to bypass an MVC route for an application where the developer left - we're going to fully replace it, but for now if I can bypass this one route, it'll save us a ton of time.

The route is (e.g.) www.this.site/path/subpath

Since it's on IIS, I can take advantage of the default document and create the following folder / file structure:  /path/subpath/index.htm

However if I do this, I'll "break" the parent www.this.site/path route (it throws a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied) because I now have an actual file folder where the /path/ route was.

Is there a way to get around this / have IIS defer to MVC on /path/ but still handle the child html file?
thanks.  Again, this is not intended as a long term solution but a work-around until we can replace the app entirely.

Comment: And if I do allow directory browsing on the IIS side by creating a /path/web.config, it's still going to break MVC route for /path/...

Comment: Perhaps [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) with a temporary redirect 302 to a root level page or real MVC page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better workaround would be to use the IIS AAR module and it's reverse proxy functionality out the app.

To do so:

a) stand up the app at it's own site the proper path -- so it should work at something like `http://localhost:1234/path/subpath/index.htm`

b) install IIS AAR module and enable the reverse proxy functions using the WebPI and the IIS management tools

c) Ignore the /path/subpath route in your app

d) Add a virtual directory for /path/subpath to IIS

e) Configure that to reverse back to localhost:1234 or whatever port you configured the site

This will keep the legacy app completely separate while keeping the public facing URLs looking correct for the rest of the world.

Comment: Thank you so much - I think this will do exactly what I need.